# Is there free data-visualization map control available for Windows Store App?

Tags: windows-8, dictionary, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, data-visualization

I searched a lot, but didn't find like that. Do you know any free data-visualization map control control as [SyncFusion](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/winrt/maps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArcGIS has released [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Windows Store 10.2 Beta](http://developers.arcgis.com/en/windows-store/)

[How to geoenrich applications with FeatureServices](http://kajanus.net/?p=362), Thanks to [Antti Kajanus](https://twitter.com/anttikajanus)